# Why is this site's rank dropping?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, pagerank

I built a site for a company a couple of months ago to bring it up to date: Proper coding, SEO, the works. *Their old site was poorly compiled HTML**

Apparently, they used a service through a company that I'm assuming added back-links all over the place and likely some black hat SEO practices.

The site has been #1 for their target search term but now it's at the bottom of page 1.

Any ideas why the sudden drop? I'm even doing SEM through google, and that's where it's dropped.

Comment: We have one catch-all question about ranking drops.  We do not offer individual site reviews here.

Comment: I'll check it out, but this thing has held a steady 1st for years and now it's dropped dramatically (it's almost at the bottom of the 2nd page now!!!) Needless to say, **I'm concerned**.

Answer (score 0):

> Apparently, they used a service through a company that I'm assuming added back-links all over the place and likely some black hat SEO practices.

You pretty much answered your own question.  Check in Webmaster Tools to see if a manual penalty is applied and also check there to see who is linking to you.  If you see a ton of questionable links, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

black hat seo practices wil kill your site in the long run. **Disavow all backlinks links you feel black hat trick**  [click here to know more about DISAVOW LINK](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en) . Start analyze your competitor sites and thier SEO efforts try to optimize your site and build trusted back links and generate genuine and unique contnet